# laptop recommendations

Tags: laptop

I am very much confused in buying either laptop  [lenovo yoga 7i](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/yoga/yoga-2-in-1-series/yoga-7i-(15)/88ygc701457?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F&cid=us:sem%7Cse%7Cgoogle%7Cbrand_consumer_yoga%7Clenovo%20yoga%207i%2015%22%7Clenovo%20yoga%207i%2015%22%7Ce%7C1608826469%7C120219793664%7Caud-962703135581:kwd-1026025078785%7Ctext%7Cbrand&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1ZGcBhCoARIsAGQ0kkrMgC2e_Oa7dcLmM9uJNtaP1pSpjifqI2CHz9X0dmxXmHx7OM9S7Q0aAtNpEALw_wcB)15 inches vs [dell xps 15 9520](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/new-xps-15-laptop/spd/xps-15-9520-laptop/xn9520ftdeh?gacd=9694607-1007-5761040-266781430-0&dgc=st&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1ZGcBhCoARIsAGQ0kkoFjftXvy12mCYIztMBMBgIFD-HDbesdlRoZhFs62fcNNREAV9AteYaAjPpEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&nclid=Hz2Tw6Eyk-3-j_SS15A41l88NDAdhbsKidTBVPE-1emrRCGgUK_5tjVpqJPANi_W)? Any suggestions? I need it for personal use mostly and also if it demands, for work.(I work as a software developer)

Comment: I assume you only compared the inside hardware like HDD, CPU and so on. I once did this mistakes and ignored the case. I have a HP notebook and the hardware is very good but not the case (shell). The plastic is very thin and unstable. This is why I recommand everyone to check the case before buying (maybe at a local store).

Answer (score 1):

As a software devver at school, I do know something about what you may need. I see the Lenovo only has a max of 16GB RAM which is kinda tight if you also use your laptop as test enviroment, so in that case the Dell is better and the Dell also has a faster CPU which may be useful if you are compiling big programs like Linux, LibreOffice, Windows (only applies if you dev there), ...

In conclusion: Dell is probably better here